# How to go into particular Directory (cd) and perform bash command(python server) in it through java?

Tags: java, bash, javafx, cd

What I want to do is: first go into some directory and start my server in the same directory for that I need to use `cd directory path` but I read previous threads and I got that **I can’t use cd command** since it is basically a system call rather than a command like `ls`.

My only aim is to go somehow in my desired directory chosen by `Directorychooser` and start `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. I tried all possible answers like using sh -c and all other solutions provided to question like how do I use cd command in java. Is this possible without using cd.
I also have address chosen by directorychooser into string address . Also how do I execute any other command in that directory. I am not sure if `Run.exec` or runtime.exec  can still help here  as it doesn't do CD I tried !

Previous answers questions doesn't explain well how to use processbuilder and other thing, Any help appreciated .

Tried these as well -

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sh -c 'cd /path/to/dir && ProgToExecute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible , I was also stuck into the same problem and I couldn’t do `cd` anywhere and this solution is how I solved it .You can achieve what you want to do with **ProcessBuilder**. (Runtime.exec() didn’t help me there as well , as suggested by previous answers on stackoverflow)
Here is how you can achieve it :

- Build the process
- Give the path
- Start the process

In code :

```
 ProcessBuilder pbuild = new ProcessBuilder(“command”); //split into number of tokens like following example
```

In your case are 3 like this :

```
 ProcessBuilder pbuild = new ProcessBuilder("python" , "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer");
```

Now set the path where the process is to be executed i.e. you are indirectly performing `cd directory-path` here

```
 pbuild.directory(new File(address));
```

(You said you have your path stored in address ,I am assuming, so)

Now start the process

```
 Process proc = pbuild.start();
```

Done! Compile and run . Command will be executed with `cd`.